# Unable to get a plot in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, math, sigmoid

I wrote a code that plots the sigmoid function. The code is pretty simple and small. It doesnt throw any error too. But when I run it, I get a white box in the plot instead of a sigmoid curve. I am unable to understand where am I going wrong. Kindly help

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as mt

def sigmoid(x):
    for i in range(10):
        x = x + 0.1
        sigmoid = (1/(1 + mt.exp(-x)))
    return x, sigmoid

x, sig = sigmoid(0)   
plt.plot(x, sig)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @DeepSpace. Should I write plt.plot twice then? one with x.arange and y.arange values? other with x and sig?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to provide `plot` an array of x values and array of y values. Instead, you are providing it a single x value and a single y value. `x` and `sigmoid` are overwritten every iteration and only the last ones are returned

Also, it is very rarely a good idea to give a function and a variable the same name.

PS your code only plots the positive side, it's missing the negative side.

Consider:

```
def sigmoid(interval):
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for x in range(-interval, interval + 1):
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(1 / (1 + mt.exp(-x)))
    return xs, ys

x, y = sigmoid(5)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Outputs

[image]

Comment: Even with x +=1 we arent getting a sigmoid

Comment: @DevLearner Because you only drew the positive side. See my updated answer